# Wampserver turns green then turns orange

Tags: wamp

The system on which wampserver was installed was hanging. After restarting the system, restarted the wampserver and it turns green and then it turns orange. When I refreshed it, it turns green then orange.

Comment: Use an elevated command prompt and run `netstat -a -b` to identify what process is already listening on the same port that your Wampserver is trying to listen to (typically 80) and failing - hence it not staying green. This can usually be if you have Skype running in the background. For a dev platform I'd suggest changing the Wamp configuration so that Apache listens on a non-standard port (8080, for example).

Comment: I am using 84 as port for Apache. Still it is not getting green.

Comment: Look at the various error logs (\wamp\logs\)

Comment: I check all the logs, error is that mysql is crashing.

Comment: When I try to open phpmyadmin, error #2002 occured

Comment: Show us the errors in the mysql error log

Answer (score 0):

The transition in colour of the WampServer icon from green to orange means that WampServer has encountered a problem that prevents it working properly.

Look at the various error logs (`\wamp\logs`) to find out the specific nature of the problem and its cause.